# AutoCompleteTextView clears user input on HTC desire Z

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an android application with a number of AutoCompleteTextView input fields

they work fine on my phone,

however when the app is deployed to a phone with a physical keyboard, as the user "tabs"
from one AutoCompleteTextView to another, the text they have selected or entered disappears from view

however the data is still present and is persisted to the underlying database

why does this only happen on their phone and not all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a very similar thing happen on a HTC Desire HD (which has no physical keyboard). Whenever the AutoCompleteTextView loses focus, the text seems to disappear (but is still accessible via getText()). Same app works fine on a Samsung Galaxy SIII, for example.

I think this is connected to using styles/themes. In my case, I had a android:textViewStyle defined, but no android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle. Adding the latter with a sensible android:textColor fixed the problem. You could also use [setTextColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29).

Excerpt from my styles.xml:

```
<style name="myapp" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/my_text_view</item>
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/my_ac_text_view</item>
    [...]
</style>

<style name="my_text_view" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="my_ac_text_view" parent="android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: stefan thanks for taking the time to look at this. i believe you are correct in that its the use of styles that are the root cause

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with a Desire HD. I set `android:textColor="#000000"` to the `AutoCompleteTextView` and it solved it without modding any style.